# Using data validation to reject duplicate entries and blank cells in a column

Tags: google-sheets

I would really appreciate it if anyone could write a data validation function that prevents someone from entering duplicate entries AND blank columns.

For example, if I entered

```
111
999
111
```

I want google sheets to reject 111.

Also, if I entered

```
111
999

123
```

I want google sheets to reject 123.

Comment: You say `google sheets` but tagged it excel.  Which is it? the methods to get the data validation are a little different.

Comment: I apologize, I am using google sheets but I thought it was interchangeable with excel.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the column is A and the cell A1 is its header, the validation rule to apply to A2:A would be "Custom formula is..." with the formula

```
=and(iserror(match(A2, A$1:A1, 0)), not(isblank(A1)))
```

Explanation:

- `match` attempts to find each cell's value in the cells above it. If there is no match, it returns #N/A error, which `iserror` converts to TRUE value.
- The second condition insists that the cell directly above the current one is not blank.
- The two are joined by `and`, so they must both hold in order for input to be valid.